# get scene from MenuItem

Tags: javafx-8

How i can get scene from MenuItem? i tried this code:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private MenuBar menuBar;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

@FXML
public void show(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(menuBar.getScene().getWindow());
stage.show();
}
```

}

the above code does not generate an error, but it does not display the window!!!

Comment: Please post the code, where the Stacktrace of your exception points to or in other words: Please post the code where the actual casting is happening..

Comment: You can change it to use root instead, root.getSene().getWindow()

Comment: @ MangO_O the error is gone, but i can't get scene from MenuItem!?, because MenuItem is not subclass of Node. what can i do?

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your Controller class add a variable for Scene with the getters and setters.
Then you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    MainController mainControls = loader.getController();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    mainControls.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Now the scene is available to all items in that class.

It looks like you're trying to create a Dialog of sorts? 
If so don't use the Main scene... create a new Stage and show that with it's content...
Although I believe the JDK comes with Dialog support now.

Comment: I forgot to add this line:stage.setScene(scene); thanks